# I can't use two images in PIL module python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make a python GUI  of a simple newspaper by using PIL module to import jpeg photos and Tkinter to label them and make a GUI. First I added one photo and it could be seen, but as soon as I added second news it disappeared. I tried putting another jpeg photo but it didn't work. I removed my 1st photo just to check that is there any problem in the photo, but when I removed my 1st photo second could be seen. Pls help and thanks in Advance!

Here's the code

```
    from tkinter import *
    from PIL import Image,ImageTk
    from datetime import datetime, date

    news = Tk()

    today = date.today()
    d2 = today.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
    my_date=datetime.today().strftime('%A')
    news.geometry("1450x900")
    news.minsize(1300,700)
    news.maxsize(2000,2000)

    news.configure(bg = "grey")



    news.title("THE TIMES OF INDIA")


    news_head = Label(text = "THE TIMES OF INDIA", font = "roboto 20 bold", bg = "white", fg = 
    "black", pady = 9,relief="groove")
     news_head.pack(side = TOP, fill = X )

     news_date1 = Label(text = d2 , font = "roboto 10 bold",bg = "lightgrey", fg = "black", p 
     pady = 2)
     news_date = Label(text = my_date, font = "roboto 10 bold", bg = "lightgrey", fg = 
     "black",pady = 1)
      news_date1.place(x = 1100, y = 30)
      news_date.place(x = 1111, y = 30)
      news_date.pack()
      news_date1.pack()

      newsf = Label(text = "News of INDIA...",padx = 30,font = "roboto 15 bold", fg = "black", 
      bg = "white")
      newsf.pack(side = TOP,fill = X,anchor ='nw')


     jo = Label(text= """Facebook on Thursday announced that it is introducing Horizon Worlds, 
     its virtual reality world of avatars, for users who are the age of 18 and above in the US 
     and Canada. 
     Eligible users who own Facebook’s Oculus virtual reality headsets can create a legless 
     avatar that 
     will wander in the animated virtual world, 
     play games, and interact with other users’ avatars. Earlier, Horizon Worlds was available 
     for select users in Beta who needed an invite to join. 
     After the announcement, users will no longer need an invite.
     """, font = "roboto 13")
     jo.place(x = 557.9, y = 350)


     image12 = Image.open(r"C:\Users\Sumit\vs code python\projects\tkinter_course\meta- 
     facebook.jpg")
     resize11 = image12.resize((450, 200))
     test = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize11)
     label1 = Label(image=test)
     label1.place(x = 30,y=350)


     sports = Label(text= """
     Senior India off-spinner Ravichandran Ashwin climbed a rung to second while his teammate 
     and opener Mayank Agarwal,
     along with New Zealand spinner Ajaz Patel, also made huge progress in the ICC Test 
     Rankings issued on Wednesday.
     Agarwal's 'Player of the Match' effort in the second Test in Mumbai, where he scored 150 
     and 62, has helped him
     gain 30 spots and reach 11th position in the latest update to the men's rankings.""", 
     font = "roboto 13")
     sports.place(x = 557.9, y = 150)


     image1 = Image.open(r"C:\Users\Sumit\vs code 
     python\projects\tkinter_course\mayankOp.jpg")
     resize1 = image1.resize((450, 200))
     test = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize1)
     label = Label(image=test)
     label.place(x = 30,y=140)

     news.mainloop()
```

I am getting this as output:
(this is the link)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLPw9.png

as you can see the second photo or the below photo is not visible

Comment: You have used same variable `test` for the two instances of `PhotoImage()`.  Use different variables.

Comment: ok got it, i just copy pasted both and dint check that